# Would the 6.5 ton capable Blue Moon lander fit in New Glenn?

Tags: launch-vehicle, lander, payload, fairings, blue-origin

As the 2 massive projects of the same company, are they designed to be compatible for NASA's [CLPS program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Lunar_Payload_Services) ? [New Glenn's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Glenn) said to have a 7 m payload fairing diameter but as far as I know, [Blue Moon's prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Moon_(spacecraft)) dimensions haven't been declared yet.

Comment: [Blue Origin said their lander can launch either on its own New Glenn vehicle or United Launch Alliance’s Vulcan](https://spacenews.com/nasa-selects-three-companies-for-human-landing-system-awards/)